# Write directly to file from BaseX GUI

Tags: xquery, basex

I wrote an XQuery expression that has a large result of about 50MB and takes a couple of hours to compute. I execute it in the BaseX GUI, but this is a little inconvenient: it crops the result to a result window, which I then have to save. At this time, BaseX becomes unresponsive and may crash.

Is there a way to directly write the result to a file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [BaseX' file module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module), which provides broad functionality to read and write from files and traverse the file system.

For you, [`file:write($path as xs:string, $items as item()*) as empty-sequence()`](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/File_Module#file:write) will be of special interest, which allows to write an element sequence to a file. For example:

```
file:write(
  '/tmp/output.xml',
  <root>{
    for $i in 1 to 1000000
    return <some-large-amount-of-data />
  }</root>
)
```

If your output isn't well-formed XML, consider the `file:write-binary`, `file:write-text` and `file:write-text-lines` functions.

Yet another alternative might be writing to documents in the database instead of files. `db:add` and `db:create` from the [database module](http://docs.basex.org/wiki/Database_Module#Updates) can be used to add the computed results to the current or a new database.

Comment: Thx, that's perfect.