# Xquery Library for writing directly to file system / base X different alternatives

Tags: xquery

I have a very similar Scenario mentioned like on this link:
[Write directly to file from BaseX GUI](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36067688/write-directly-to-file-from-basex-gui/36071116#)

but I cant use base X

My XQY works fine BUT for customer requirement, the size doubled and from 60 mbs it became 160 mbs and in runtime it just got stucked. so like XSLT, I want to write the result to File System

do you know any library or api similar? cant find one

regards

Comment: BaseX has a command line mode as well, also of course various APIs in other languages so you don't need to use the BaseX GUI. As for other ways to run XQuery, Saxon 9.8 or 9.9 or Saxon 10.0 are XQuery 3.1 processors, version 10 having the advantage that the open-source HE edition includes support for higher-order functions. https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/10/Java/ has the download or if you write Java code you can find it on Maven as well. Whether a non DB version of XQuery solves memory problems I am not sure.

Comment: thanks martin look the thing is that it for a project funcionality so it is not a one time shot issue

Comment: StackOverflow discourages questions that ask for advice on choosing products. The reason is that it's very hard to give enough clear information about your requirements to allow an objective answer, so the questions tend to attract answers from everyone saying what their favourite products are. The way you have described your requirements is certainly not good enough. You've hinted that you have a performance problem, for example, but there certainly isn't enough detail for anyone to know whether a particular choice of product will solve that problem.

Comment: hello michael kay, Im asking for alternatives , and indeed I only found one , it is EXPath file module related to SAXON  : http://expath.org/spec/file